# Why does a voltage divider linearize the effects of a non-linear thermistor?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, thermistor

I saw a design specification with an NTC thermistor in a voltage-divider configuration.
[image: Schematic]

The design method said that we must have $$R_1=\sqrt{R_{NTC\min}R_{NTC\max}}$$ to produce a **linear output voltage** for a given range despite \$R_{NTC}\$ being highly non-linear (Why?)

Isn't the effect of \$R_1\$ to make the seen resistance or the Thevenin resistance to be close to \$R_1\$ if \$R_{NTC}\$ is sufficiently large or in other words $$
\frac{R_1 R_{NTC}}{R_1 + R_{NTC}}
$$ is not a linear equation nor does it linearize the highly non-linear thermistor even for a given range. So we still have a non-linear input voltage at the Op-amp

I can't see why the output voltage will be linear even for any value of \$R_1\$

Comment: I would not have thought it was linear either. I'm suspicious. I don't think it's that easy to linearize it since if it was I would expect that to be everywhere and I've never seen it. Maybe it is *really* bad wording that is supposed to mean to produce a linear approximation over a range of interest. That would make a lot more sense looking at the method's equation.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm sorry, looks like the linearize term I used caused confusion, I meant that the output voltage is linearized for the range, say 25 to 50 °C. Still, my question holds since I can't answer why the output voltage will act linearly even for a range

Comment: It's not actually linear. To linearize means to figure out a way to minimize the error when you treat it (pretend) it is linear. In this case, it's to pick a point in the temperature range of interest where this occurs. But I imagine you have to figure out whether the error is acceptable or not since if you choose an enormous range, your error could be unacceptably large even if it the minimum you could have.

Comment: It's still not linear, no matter what you do resistor wise.  You can make it less logarithmic, over a limited temperature range, but not truly linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No linearization takes place in the op-amp circuit, so you can ignore that in any analysis. They are just saying that to make the best of a bad bargain the series resistor should be the geometric mean of the end points of the range in resistance. Another way to look at it is that the \$\Delta V/\Delta T\$ is maximized at the temperature where the thermistor resistance equals the series resistor resistance. The output per degree decreases on either side of that value.

By adding series resistance to a bridge circuit it is possible to get an S-shaped error from linear that is fairly good over a relatively narrow range of temperatures, at a cost of complexity and output, however the fearsome nonlinearity of the thermistor wins out over a wider range, so schemes involving resistor networks with multiple thermistor elements are sometimes used.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9hZPY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This works because the energizing voltage of the bridge proper varies in the desirable direction with the thermistor resistance (as the thermistor resistance increases at low temperatures, the energizing voltage goes up, increasing the output per degree). I played around with this a few days ago, mostly to see how easy it would be to do with modern tools (using python scripts and libraries and extended Steinhart-Hart equations). You can see [one result](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595687/averaging-thermistor-readings/595689#595689) here.

However, in 2021, a  more sensible approach in most cases is to provide an ADC with a lot of dynamic range and deal the the nonlinearity in the digital domain.

Answer (score 4):

In fact it doesn't.

Typical NTC law is exponential, this turns into a cold to hot resistance ratio that may well be in the hundreds depending on temperature range considered.
No chance to get it done but some clever numerical algorithm later on, after the ADC.

On the other hand if temperature range is small choosing R1=R(NTC) Is done to have the highest sensitivity, voltage variation per degree.

So the design method you choose is just optimize at the geometric mean of resistance. This can prove good enough depending on results you're after.

Consider that any linear circuit you may think trying to linearize is equivalent to the voltage divider you are actually using, so choosing equivalent resistance seen (your R1) is the only degree of freedom.

---

Saying that the network is linear should be enough to prove that the NTC port can be modelled as its Thevenin voltage and resistance, while the voltage output to the measuring circuit is a linear combination of some offset and a fraction of the NTC voltage
$$V_\mathrm{out}=V_\mathrm{out,0}+\alpha \,V_\mathrm{Rt} $$

But I'd like to go through some details. Let's take any generic linear network including excitation, output nodes but the NTC Rt itself.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9MxkH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It can always be modelled by (mutliport) Thevenin
$$\mathbf{V}=\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{R}\cdot\mathbf{I}$$
with **V** and **I** port voltage and current vectors, **E** the open circuit Thevenin voltage vector and **R** the resistances matrix.

Expanding the matrix notation we have:

$$\left\{ \begin{align} 
V_1=&E_1+R_{11}I_1+R_{12}I_2 \\ 
V_2=&E_2+R_{21}I_1+R_{22}I_2 
\end{align}\right. $$

---

Now the left port #1 can be analyzed, we can assume without any loss of generality (1) that I2=0 i.e. the measuring circuit is a high impedance one.

*(1) If it were not, measuring system input resistance can always taken inside N and crunched into the resistance matrix.*

So we have
$$ V_\mathrm{Rt}=V_1=E_1+R_{11}I_1 $$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB0ASK.png)</sup>

That's clearly the classical Thevenin equivalent, whatever you have inside the blackbox network N1 the NTC just sees a voltage generator and resistance.

---

Let's now have a look to the output port 2 equation in the same premise I2=0
$$ V_{out}=V_2=E_2+R_{21}I_1 $$
I1 current can be found from port 1
$$ V_\mathrm{Rt}=E_1+R_{11}I_1\quad\quad\Rightarrow\quad\quad
I_1=\frac{V_\mathrm{Rt}-E_1}{R_{11}}$$
Which substituted above
$$ V_{out}=V_2=E_2+R_{21}\frac{V_\mathrm{Rt}-E_1}{R_{11}}=
\underbrace{E_2-\frac{R_{21}}{R_{11}}E_1}_{V_\mathrm{out,0}}+
\underbrace{\frac{R_{21}}{R_{11}}}_{\alpha}V_\mathrm{Rt}$$

$$V_\mathrm{out}=V_\mathrm{out,0}+\alpha \,V_\mathrm{Rt} $$

---

Put it simple, whatever linear network you invent to connect your NTC it all boils down to be equivalent to

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffONxC.png)</sup>

Voltage and resistance drive with offset \$V_\mathrm{out,0} \$ and gain factor \$\alpha\$ between NTC voltage VRt and network output.